# C# switch expression / pattern matching - when clause inside or

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-10.0

Consider the following:

```cs
var ch = 'i';
var str = "some item";

var result = ch switch
            {
                'a' => DoA("some", "parameters"),
                _ when str.Contains("action a") => DoA("some", "parameters"),
                'b' => DoB("some", "parameters"),
                _ when str.Contains("action b") => DoB("some", "parameters"),
                'c' => DoC(),
                _ when str.Contains("action c") => DoC("some", "parameters"),
                _ => new Exception("")
            };
```

Now you can see the repetition when calling the methods, so Ideally I would like something like this:

```cs
var result = ch switch
            {
                'a' or (_ when str.Contains("action a")) => DoA("some", "parameters"),
                'b' or (_ when str.Contains("action b")) => DoB("some", "parameters"),
                'c' or (_ when str.Contains("action c")) => DoC("some", "parameters"),
                _ => new Exception("")
            };
```

But this gets me a syntax error.
Removing the brackets does compile, but then the logic is equivalent to
`('a' or _) when str.Contains("action a")) => DoA("some", "parameters")`
which is not what I want.

Is there a way to do it correctly without duplication?

Comment: No. When `when` clause comes after the pattern, and you're trying to fold it into the pattern itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
var result = ch switch
{
   _ when ch == 'a' || str.Contains("action a") => ...
```

<sub>***Note** : I personally dislike this type switch expression, it's kind of meh and ugly looking*</sub>

Or the other option is just do it the old fashioned way and create a method `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
public Bob DoSomething(char ch)
{
   if(ch =='a' || str.Contains("action a"))
       return DoA("some", "parameters");
   ...
```